# How to use apprequest to redirect user to the application profile page instead of the canvas page?

Tags: facebook, invite, apprequests

We are working on a web-based game and we would like to promote it via Facebook. Currently we are using facebook connect to allow user to login and post game related messages to their wall via wall posts, FB.ui({method: 'feed', ...);. In addition we like to our users to invite other users to join our game. For this we use apprequest, FB.ui({method: 'apprequests' ....); However this will lead the invited users to the canvas page, which we don't have. We could workaround this by creating a canvas page in facebook and let it simply redirect users to where we want. But is there a cleaner way to lead the users to the application profile page or the web site it self?

My thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Albert see: [How can I redirect to my app page after accepted a app request sent from our app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7639264/how-can-i-redirect-to-my-app-page-after-accepted-a-app-request-sent-from-our-app/7639397#7639397)

In short, you will need to pass the redirect url in the data parameter of the request and use javascript to do the redirect once the user has landed on the canvas page.